# Race condition : updating a structure can return half an old pointer and half a new pointer

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14, shared-ptr, data-synchronization

```
void ZMDAggregator::getMZMap(DataModel::MZMap &mZM)
{
    LOGGER_EVENT("ZMDAggregator getMZMap()");
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lockSlot(internalStateMutex);    
    mZM.clear();
    mZM = this->mZM;        
}

void ZMDAggregator::Roscallback(const ros::MZMap msgMZMap)
{   
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lockSlot(internalStateMutex);
    MZMap map;
    for( auto const & entry : msgMZMap.m_z_e)
    {
        mzEntry.clear();
        mzEntry.mID = entry.mID;
        mzEntry.tMode = entry.tMode;
        mzEntry.areaID = entry.areaID;
        mzEntry.oZone = entry.oZone;        
        mzEntry.authZ = entry.authZ;
        mzEntry.blockZ = entry.blockZ;        
        map.mzEntry.push_back(mzEntry);                        
    }
}
```

The above function gets called around 30 times a second.This is causing a high cpu utilization in my program.

```
struct MZEntry
{       
    uint32_t mID;
    bool tMode;
    uint32_t areaID;        
    uint32_t oZone;        
    using ZList = std::vector<uint32_t>;
    ZList authZ;        
    ZList blockZ;        
};

struct MZMap
{
    std::vector<MZEntry> mzEntry;
}

Class ZMDAggregator {    
    mutable std::mutex internalStateMutex;
    MZMap mzMap;
}
```

My question is if I convert `getMZMap()` to accept a shared_ptr instead of a reference and also change the type of the member variable `mzMap` to a shared_ptr as shown below.

```
void ZMDAggregator::getMZMap(std::shared_ptr<DataModel::MZMap> &mZM)
{
    LOGGER_EVENT("ZMDAggregator getMZMap()");
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lockSlot(internalStateMutex);        
    mZM = this->mZM;        
}

Class ZMDAggregator {

    mutable std::mutex internalStateMutex;
    std::shared_ptr<DataModel::MZMap> mzMap;
}
```

My question is as follows.

My class `ZMDAggregator` updates the structure once every 50 milliseconds, so around 20 times a second As you can see this happens inside the `unique_lock`.
The Thread that calls, getMZMap() calls it around 20 times a second.

By modifying initial structure to a `shared_ptr`, I should be able to bring down CPU cycles, as a struct copy is now avoided. However now since the same pointer is being accessed in the caller thread (Reader)
there is a risk that I can get half an old pointer and half a new pointer when the function `Roscallback` updates the structure.

Without using a mutex, (These two functions are two separate classes) is there a way to ensure that the above scenario doesn't occour ?

As per the suggestion of @freakish, I have returned shared_ptr by value. Please find the code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct MZEntry
{
    uint32_t mID;
    bool tMode;
    uint32_t areaID;
    uint32_t oZone;
    using ZList = std::vector<uint32_t>;
    ZList authZ;
    ZList blockZ;
};

struct MZMap
{
    std::vector<MZEntry> mzEntry;
};

class A
{
public:
    void populate()
    {
        std::cout << "A populate()" << std::endl;
        MZEntry mzEntry;
        mzEntry.mID = 55;
        mzEntry.tMode = true;
        mzEntry.areaID = 55;
        mzEntry.oZone = 55;
        mzEntry.authZ = {1,2,3};
        mzEntry.blockZ = {4,5,6};
        l->mzEntry.push_back(mzEntry);
    }
    std::shared_ptr<MZMap> assign() const
    {
        return l;
    }
    std::shared_ptr<MZMap> l;

    A()
    {
        std::cout << "A constructor()" << std::endl;
        l = std::make_shared<MZMap>();
        populate();
    }
};

class B
{
public:

    B()
    {
        std::cout << "B constructor" << std::endl;
        a = new A();
    }
    void getValue()
    {
        std::cout << "B getValue()" << std::endl;
        p3 = a->assign();
    }
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "machineID:  " << p3->mzEntry[0].mID << std::endl;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<MZMap> p3;
    A *a;
};

int main() {

    B *b = new B();

    b->getValue();
    b->print();
    return 0;
}
```

So what you are saying is in the line

```
    p3 = a->assign();
```

It doesn't do a struct copy, instead it just increments the reference count? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I don't understand why you use shared_ptr and pass it by reference. Isn't that pointless? Did you mean to use unique_ptr? Also, locks were created to solve synchronization issues. Are you looking for a lock-free solution? Why? Either way this looks like a messy design.

Comment: `ZMDAggregator::Roscallback` uses a name `mzEntry` that doesn't appear to be declared anywhere. It's also unclear why it's locking the mutex - it doesn't appear to touch the object's sole data member in any way.

Comment: The second version of `ZMDAggregator::getMZMap` refers to `this->mZM`, but `ZMDAggregator` doesn't have a member named `mZM`

Comment: @freakish - what is wrong in passing shared_ptr by reference ?

Comment: @liv2hak let me put it differently: why do you use shared_ptr here? The only reason to use this pointer is when it is passed by value (so that ref counter increments) and actually shared. You can pass it by reference, but then what's the point? You've added shared_ptr's overhead for no reason. It seems to me that unique_ptr is what you are looking for here.

Comment: @freakish - I think, I got it. I have updated a working new code, can you please comment on the question. thank you very much